# How do I generate canceled requests for a spring GatewayFilter test?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-webflux

The filter's `filter()` method looks like this:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    return chain.filter(exchange).doFinally(signal -> {
            LOGGER.info("Signal: " + signal.name()); // never says CANCEL
            // ...
        });
    }
}
```

I need to write unit tests that make sure the signal takes all possible values from `reactor.core.publisher.SignalType`.

I can't seem to be able to generate a `CANCEL` event. The test uses Mockito and should look something like this, as far as I can tell (minus all things that I tried and which didn't work):

```
    Mono<Void> aMono = Mono.empty();
    // here I should do stuff to the mono so it gets canceled - but what?
    when(chain.filter(exchange)).thenReturn(aMono);
    Mono<Void> filtered = filter.filter(exchange, chain).block();
    // assertions should start here
```

Both `chain` and `exchange` are mocks. `filter` is the object under test.

Comment: Can i please ask out of curiosity why you need to write code that tests an internal spring reactor enum? Im pretty confident that they have already tested that the event works.

Comment: I don't want to test the enum. I want to test that a filter I added reacts properly to every type of signal. I can verify this for error and success, but not for cancel.

Answer (score 0):

It will never emit `CANCEL` signal. When the publisher completes work, it will send a `ON_COMPLETE` signal type.

```
chain.filter(exchange).doFinally(signal -> {
   LOGGER.info("Signal: " + signal.name()); // It must print ON_COMPLETE
});
```

Also, it's a bad way to test reactive streams like above way. Look at `reactor-test` (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor/reactor-test/3.4.6)  lib. There are awesome utils, one of these is `StepVerifier` that helps you test reactive streams. For example:

```
StepVerifier.create(chain.filter(exchange))
   .verifyComplete();
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, that it will never emit cancel. But I see cancel in the logs, for no apparent reason. I had behavior in place for success and error, but, since some streams were canceled even if they shouldn't have been, I need to add behavior for cancel too - and test it. But I can't seem to be able to reproduce that misterious situation in tests.